# Physics tab is not appearing for the hair particle emitter system

Tags: particles, hair, settings

I am watching a tutorial and the user has a physics tab in the hair particle emitter but I do not, how do I make this appear? I've included screenshots of my screen versus theirs.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried checking "advanced"

Comment: that worked, thanks